# Is Helmholtz energy $F$ a concave (convex upward) function of T?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

According to a textbook, "$F = U - TS$ is a concave function of $T$, because $U$ is a convex function of $S$."

I don't understand this statement. Could anyone please tell me the detailed reason?

(Here, $U$ is internal energy, $S$ entropy and $T$ temperature.)

Supplement: I found some analytical (relatively longer) proofs on websites, but don't still understand why that short statement can also be the proof.

Comment: Did you try to work through this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation#Properties

Comment: @Photon Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted. Now I understand the short statement is enough.